# jQuery - Send a form asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form such as :

```
<form action='???' method='post' name='contact'>
        <input type="text" class="inputContact" name="mittente" />
        <textarea class="textContact" name="smex"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to send these data asynchronously, trought jQuery function `$.ajax`.

**EDIT :with solution :**

```
<form name='contactForm'>
    <input type="text" class="inputContact" name="mittente" />
    <textarea class="textContact" name="smex"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[name=contactForm]').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: './ajax/header_ajax.php',
            data: 'id=header_contact_send&'+$(this).serialize(), 
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#boxContentId").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });     
});         
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? You already know that you have to (or want to) use `$.ajax`. I guess you already read its documentation. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'd like to know how to perfom $.ajax by clicking on the button "Send"

Comment: Just a side note: using the `name` attribute in `form` is depreciated as of HTML4. The `id` attribute should be used instead.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$('form[name=contact]').submit(function(){

    // Maybe show a loading indicator...

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res){
        // Do something with the response `res`
        console.log(res);
        // Don't forget to hide the loading indicator!
    });

    return false; // prevent default action

});
```

See:

- [jQuery docs: post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post)
- [jQuery docs: serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize)

Comment: From my tests it doesn't.

Comment: @Hadesara async file upload here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously#8758614