# AEM OOTB Form Component and AJAX Submission

Tags: ajax, forms, adobe, aem

I'm evaluating AEM 6.2 OOTB forms component to build a Newsletter signup form with AJAX submission, this is not AEM Forms that is licensed separately.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/components/developing-forms.html

I have not used this component previously, can someone advise on the following:

1. Can I make the form submit request via AJAX and capture response from the server side / API (asynchronous)?
2. Is there limitation in terms of styling capability? I'm trying to achieve the same signup form at the bottom of this page https://westernstarbutter.com.au/en/recipes/ham_-cheese-and-veggie-bake.html
3. Any other limitations / gotchas that I should be aware of?

Would love to hear some advices on this, would be great if someone can share some implementations as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make the form submit request via AJAX and capture response from the server side / API (asynchronous)?

I don't believe you can do this OOTB - it's certainly not part of the actions list but it wouldn't be too hard to create a custom action and add the necessary Javascript code to hook into the form submission.

> Is there limitation in terms of styling capability?

Not really - just add your own CSS and off you go.

> Any other limitations / gotchas that I should be aware of?

I remember the validation being very limiting, especially if validation of a field is dependent on another field.

Comment: Just to add to your answer about asynchronously submitting a form, here is an SO answer that has a minimal working solution to converting form submission to an async request using jquery:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985093/jquery-send-a-form-asynchronously it would not be hard to hook this into the form's submission and you end up with async form, as easy as possible.